# how to make one by one completion of methods using block?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

I have 3 methods in which i want that all complete execution one by one.

It probably be done using blocks but i cant learn how to create own blocks. Or Is there any other way to achieve this?

I have scenario as,

Also same scenario without blocks & all is running fine in ios6 but os lower than that is not working

```
[self getIndex];
[self expandrows]; //I want this expandrows to be called only after everything in getIndex is finished.

-(void)getIndex
    {
     [self didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     //Once this didselect is completed execution than after only i want to start this loop
            for (int index = 0; index < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; index++)
           {
                NSMutableDictionary *aMutDicCur = [self.model itemForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
                if([[aMutDicCur valueForKey:@"CategoryId"] intValue] == 4)
                {
                    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
                    break;
                }
           }

    //After this loop finishes i need to again call one other method
    }
```

As far as I know blocks are asynchronous.So in that case

Comment: try to call that method from inside getIndex function itself.

Comment: Also loop getting started without completion of didSelect

Comment: I get to know by debugging that [self didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] is not expanding ma table view cell in ios5.1 but working in ios6

Comment: Your [self didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] is not in an if clause, which I think you intend it to be. If you simply want [self expandrows] to be called when the loop ends, just put the call there (as Nirav suggests). You don't need blocks and probably want to get to a point where you really understand what's going wrong here before you look into them.

Comment: hey roshni, i am not getting you .can you elaborate me what your problem is ??

Comment: I found the solution by putting         `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) withObject:indexPath waitUntilDone:YES];` after that I start call my for loop & called [self expandrows] with some delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call this [self expandrows]; after when you finish your second method call which is call in

get index method.

Comment: This was very near to my problems solution so I am accepting this answer

Comment: yes i called the method on main thread so that it finish first and after that i called next method and at the end of that i called 3rd method